# is_dir How to check if dir exists avoid error message

Tags: php, regex

I think I have missed something with the code below... Maybe you can help

```
<?php
    $imageurl = $pagename1;
    $imageurl = preg_replace('/\.asp/', ''.$g_sites_img2.'.jpg', $pagename1);
    $filename = $_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.'/images'.$imageurl;
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo '<img src="'.$mainurl.'/images'.$imageurl.'" width="'.$g_sites_img2.'" align="left" />';
    } else {
        $imgremoteurl = $imgremoteurl.str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($g_page_identify));
        $imageurlfolder = dirname($pagename1);
        mkdir($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.'/images'.$imageurlfolder, 0755, true);
        copy('http://www.dominate-seo.com/images/'.$imgfolder.'/'.$imgremoteurl.'.jpg', $_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.'/images'.$imageurl);
        $thumb = new Imagick($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.'/images'.$imageurl);
        $thumb->scaleImage($g_sites_img2, 0);
        $thumb->writeImage($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.'/images'.$imageurl);
        $thumb->destroy();
    }
?>
```

The code is suppose to check if a image exist. If the image does not exists it should create the image folder, but should not create it if it already exists. This is where my problem lies. If the folder exists it gives me an error

> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]:
>   File exists in
>   /home/game1/public_html/includes

If I refresh the page, the error message disappears when the file is created.

How can I write the script so that it checks the folder, if it exists it does not throw the error?

Comment: It would be nice if you could add line breaks to the PHP code...

Comment: You should accept the answer that is fit to your answer by clicking the tick mark with the answer. Otherwise you may loose the power to ask a question in this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're showing all errors.  For this operation, I think the easiest is to just try to make the folder and suppress your error messages by adding an '@' symbol in front of your mkdir:

```
@mkdir($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.'/images'.$imageurlfolder);
```

Answer (score 3):

The is_dir() method returns false if the directory doesn't exist. Instead of just suppressing the error you could replace the mkdir() line with this check:

```
if(!is_dir($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'} . '/images' . $imageurlfolder)) {
   // Create the directory since it doesn't exist.
   mkdir($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'} . '/images' . $imageurlfolder, 0755, true);
}
```